# Google Web Toolkit - XSRF Protected Services : Invalid RPC Token

Tags: gwt, csrf

I've implemented XSRF Protected Services in GWT project. I'm using GWT 2.6.0 release. When I try to load my app in a browser I get a very strange exception as follows:

Uncaught com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RpcTokenException: Invalid RPC token (Invalid RpcToken type: expected 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.XsrfToken' but got 'class com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.XsrfToken')

I've searched my classpath and I only have one XsrfToken class provided by gwt-servlet.jar located inside my WAR file. I downloaded 2.6 code from GIT and I see the code that is throwing the exception is provided by ProxyCreator.java in the method generateCheckRpcTokenTypeOverride.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this exception would be thrown. The error indicates to me at least that it should pass given that what is expected is what it has.

I'm pasting the method in for completeness:

`protected void generateCheckRpcTokenTypeOverride(SourceWriter srcWriter, TypeOracle typeOracle,
      SerializableTypeOracle typesSentFromBrowser) {
    JClassType rpcTokenType = typeOracle.findType(RpcToken.class.getName());
    JClassType[] rpcTokenSubtypes = rpcTokenType.getSubtypes();
    String rpcTokenImplementation = "";
    for (JClassType rpcTokenSubtype : rpcTokenSubtypes) {
      if (typesSentFromBrowser.isSerializable(rpcTokenSubtype)) {
        if (rpcTokenImplementation.length() > 0) {
          // >1 implematation of RpcToken, bail
          rpcTokenImplementation = "";
          break;
        } else {
          rpcTokenImplementation = rpcTokenSubtype.getQualifiedSourceName();
        }
      }
    }
    if (rpcTokenImplementation.length() > 0) {
      srcWriter.println("@Override");
      srcWriter.println("protected void checkRpcTokenType(RpcToken token) {");
      srcWriter.indent();
      srcWriter.println("if (!(token instanceof " + rpcTokenImplementation + ")) {");
      srcWriter.indent();
      srcWriter.println("throw new RpcTokenException(\"Invalid RpcToken type: " + "expected '"
          + rpcTokenImplementation + "' but got '\" + " + "token.getClass() + \"'\");");
      srcWriter.outdent();
      srcWriter.println("}");
      srcWriter.outdent();
      srcWriter.println("}");
    }
  }`

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Development or production? What happens if you reload the page?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I'm using production mode and if I reload the page I get same error. I've cleaned my cache etc. Tried multiple browsers too.

Comment: Are you following http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html ?

Comment: Yes and no. We have very large project used by lots of customers in the  real world. I did not inherit my servlet from XsrfProtectedServlet but provide same functionality in my own servlets. However, on the client I most certainly do. I've got it setup so user will only have to change some servlet definitions in web.xml and also add a late/deferred binding into their gwt.xml file. Depending on the binding the client will create "normal" services or "protected" services. I will try to inherit from the XsrfProtectedServlet to see if it changes anything but was hoping I wouldn't have to.

Comment: I solved this problem myself. I believe it Was a weird side affect of my client side service creation which has since been greatly simplified. I was attempting to create token service and acquire server generated token inside the context of a GWT.create for a protected service. I know... right?

Result of trying to support existing customers using unprotected services as well as new customers that require protected services via deferred binding. Customers can upgrade as see fit but we won't force them. They could simply change a deferred binding in their gwt.xml file and get protected services

Comment: We changed our mind and decided to always have our services be protected.

Changed my code to first get XSRF Token before doing anything. Once token is received, I then create the protected services, assign token and uncaught exception handlers and all is well. Tried to fit square peg in round hole.